# How to replace a letter in string with any other letter but itself, or adjacent ones in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Lets say I have a string `'xyxxxyx'`. I want to replace `x` in middle, with any other letter except (`x` and `y` (adjacent letters) to make a string so that every adjacent letter is different.

As an example

```
Input: 'xyxxxyx'  
Output: 'xyxzxyx'
```

I want this to be generic for any input string.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is `y` excepted? A result of `xyxyxyx` still seems to meet your criteria. Also, please provide what you have so far so we know where to start from.

Comment: What do you mean by " replace `x` in middle". What if the string is an even length and there is no difinitive "middle" of the string. What are the standard inputs? Will they always be `x`'s and `y`'s? There is just NOT enough info here to help you.

Comment: Here is my  code, for i in range (1,len(str)):
    if str[i]==str[i-1]:
        count+=1
        str[i] = 'p'
but I am just replacing with any letter 'p', it is not generic.
@Jab, yes the goal is to have adjacent letters different, I just took one sample as example to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
a='xyxxxyx'
import string
from random import randint
total=[x for x in list(string.ascii_lowercase) if x not in spil] # gets alphabets a to z in a list except the ones in a

spil=list(a) #spilt the string a in letters
for i in range(len(spil)-1):
    if spil[i]==spil[i+1]: #if two consecitive are same then changes the next one with a random alphabet

        spil[i]=total[randint(0,len(total))]
print("".join(spil))
```

The output will be :

```
'xyczxyx'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with regular expressions:

```
import re

def noDoubles(string):
    subChars = set("wxyz")
    result   = list(string)
    for match in re.finditer(r"(.)(\1+)",string):
        usedChars = set(string[match.start():match.end()+1])
        altChars  = list(subChars - usedChars)
        size      = match.end(2) - match.start(2)
        size      = size - (size>1) 
        result[match.start(2):match.start(2)+size] = (altChars[:2]*size)[:size]
    return "".join(result)

print(noDoubles("xyxxxyaaabbyyaaaaa")) # "xyxzxyazabzyzazwza"
```

The expression (.)(\1+) finds the first character and subsequent repetitions of a string of repeated characters. Looping through the matches will allow you to replace that subsequent part with an alternating pattern of characters that are not the one being repeated nor the one following that.  You need use an alternating pattern for replacement so that you don't create new repetitions.

Note that we only need to work with 4 substitution characters because the repeated character and the next character are either going to be one or two of the 4 (leaving two for the alternance) or none of them (which lets us use any two out of the 4).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve your question with `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import groupby

def rep_adj(data, char='z'): 
    for _, v in groupby(data): 
        b = list(v) 
        if len(b) > 0: 
            for i, j in enumerate(b): 
                yield char if not i%2==0 else j

data = 'xyxxxyx' 
out = ''.join(rep_adj(data))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
'xyxzxyx'
```